# new drive in Ubuntu Desktop 14.04

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I am using a new hard drive(non SSD, plain old hard drive) which is already ext4 formatted and mounted at /media/mynewdrive after following this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive)

But i want to mount it at /opt as most of the software are being installed there. Currently i need to manually move the stuff to /media/mynewdrive and underneath...not very convenient location to remember....
What should I do? I already have /opt and the sub directories in my old drive which i want to keep intact.
This is my current mount command output:

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/home/ashu# mount
/dev/sda7 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sdb3 on /media/mynewdrive type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ashu)
/dev/sr0 on /media/ashu/CD0001 type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks2)
root@ashu-700-430qe:/home/ashu#
```

It's dual boot system with Windows 10 and i don't want to impact any other stuff.

```
root@ashu-700-430qe:/home/ashu# blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Windows RE tools" UUID="10E664BBE664A2A8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="E467-1A3B" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Windows" UUID="C0726845726841F0" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="CC8C4A768C4A5ADA" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="74a0518b-2eed-404a-aaa1-a302dbf9f18c" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="54458154-6f44-44c9-be44-f91d093d63e6" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda8: LABEL="Recovery Image" UUID="90686954686939DC" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="Windows_F" UUID="380C233F0C22F790" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb3: UUID="f44ccbce-3388-475e-9d41-5228b388f282" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="CD0001" TYPE="iso9660" 


root@ashu-700-430qe:/home/ashu# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=54458154-6f44-44c9-be44-f91d093d63e6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=E467-1A3B  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=74a0518b-2eed-404a-aaa1-a302dbf9f18c none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb3    /media/mynewdrive   ext4    defaults     0        2
(rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=hal,shortname=mixed,uid=1000,utf8,umask=077,flush)
```

Comment: You could mount it at: /opt/mynewdrive

Comment: Please also provide the contents of `fstab` and the output to `blkid`. Then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: @Fabby. Added the desired info in the question.

Comment: You've self-answered *and accepted*...  I fail to see why you still ping me???  **:-/**

Comment: @Fabby...pinged in case if there is something better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possible options after talking to some of the Linux Gurus that I know:

1. I could use LVM , that allows  to add new physical disks, and physical volume (a partition) to a logical volume (a mounted partition),  an existing logical volume (say `/opt` ) can be extended with the extra space provided by new physical volume.
2. Another option as my `/` and `/media/mynewdrive` are both of type `ext4` I can copy everything onto new partition(the one which is mounted as `/media/mynewdrive`) and then mount that as `/opt`

Looking for some options and will go with the one which suits my needs in the best possible manner.